# How to find purchase details of a specific customer in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, join

I have a MYSQL assignment and I had to work on 10 queries. I have developed the MYSQL code for 9 queries and stuck on one. In this query, we are given the name of a customer and we have to show the purchases done by this customer. We have to use natural join to complete this task. The tables provided are shown below:

Table for customers. Table name 'CUSTOMER'

```
CUS_CODE|CUS_LNAME|CUS_FNAME|CUS_INITIAL|CUS_AREACODE|CUS_PHONE|CUS_BALANCE
```

Table for purchases is shown below. Table name 'INVOICE'

```
INV_NUMBER|CUS_CODE|INV_DATE|INV_SUBTOTAL|INV_TAX|INV_TOTAL
```

The question states:

> List all the purchases made by customer Orlando (use a natural join).

I have tried some solutions from the internet and some from my own but they are not correct; either they have syntax error or are not producing the desired result.

Comment: Show us the solutions you attempted, and the error messages that resulted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM customers c
NATURAL JOIN purchases p
WHERE c.CUS_LNAME = "Orlando"
```

Comment: Thanks. The solution is working.